# Getting 404 error on a page when url is using item name

Tags: urls

I keep on getting this annoying error when I'm trying to navigate to my site's page: `{siteurl}/projects/name-of-project`. But it is okay when: `{siteurl}/projects/{item id}`.

Where in `{item id}` is the `project id` (the page itself)

What I did so far:

```
1. Published master to web
2. Clear cache
3. Re-index
```

Comment: {siteurl}/projects/{item id} , what is item id , please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several reasons why you are seeing this weird behavior. Some of them are listed below:

1. Is it happening for all the pages?
   **If yes, you need to check the sitedefinition.config**
2. Does the page have a Layout and rendering. **If not, you need to make sure that the page has a valid layout and renderings associated so that it can be visible in front end.**
3. Is the item stuck in workflow and hence not published in web database? **Move the item to the final workflow state and try browsing the URL.**
4. Is there any custom rendering due to which the page is breaking and redirecting to 404? **Check the logs for any error related to your custom code. Try disabling renderings one by one and check if the page loads or not.**

Comment: Indeed. A stuck in workflow causes this. :( Thank you for making me realize this.

Comment: Ya I've faced this several times myself.